# Constant receiving UDP packets from other local PC and firewall failed to block that specific IP address

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, udp

Is it normal for a PC to keep sending out UDP packets to other local devices using random source ports?

In my case, I'm using Wireshark to monitor my own Windows PC network and I found there is one IP address constantly sending a UDP packet to my PC port 2054.
The source port is almost random as I hardly find any repeated port numbers.

I checked the ports' activity but I do not know how to log it into some kind of text file. So I do not know what application is using port 2054. Netstat results do not show this port number.

I also tried blocking IP address inbound and outbound but my PC is still receiving the packet. I configured this using Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security. Since I am using a public Wi-Fi network, I only block the inbound and outbound of IP address of the device sending me packets. Set block by Any program, Any local port and Any remote port.

Any idea on this case?

Comment: Exceedingly few protocols specify a well-known client source port. Most often, any free port in the ephemeral port range (49152-65535) is automatically assigned to any process that wants to send a UDP frame. So that's normal.

Comment: Even if I'm in a networks that have multiple PC but only receive UDP constantly from a PC?